# Session issue with SWF uploader in safari

Tags: php, zend-framework, swfupload

I am using SWFuploader with Jquery and PHP(Zend framework) for uploading

http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/

I am facing a problem while using sessions.
There is **3 step** login wizard, 1st step is simple form and uplaoder is on **2nd step**.
Flow of application is, It stores **1st step data in session** after submitting and redirect to 2nd step. When I try to upload some files and try to use data stored in session, it gives me nothing.

I am using this code :
JS Code

```
var settings = {
        flash_url : "/javascript/flash/swfupload.swf",
        upload_url: "/login/uploaditems", 
        post_params: {
                      'session' : <?php echo session_id;?>
                 },
        file_size_limit : "1 MB",
    file_types : "*.pdf;",
    file_types_description : "All Files",
    file_upload_limit : 100,
    file_queue_limit : 10,
    custom_settings : {
        cancelButtonId : "cancelBtn"
    },
    debug: false,
    button_image_url: "/images/chooseButton-2.png",

    // The event handler functions are defined in handlers.js
    file_queued_handler : fileQueued,
    file_queue_error_handler :fileQueueError,
    file_dialog_complete_handler : fileDialogComplete,
    upload_start_handler : uploadStart,
    upload_progress_handler : uploadProgress,
    upload_error_handler : uploadError,
    upload_success_handler : uploadSuccess,
    upload_complete_handler : uploadComplete,
    queue_complete_handler : queueComplete  // Queue plugin event
};

Swfu1 = new SWFUpload(settings);
```

PHP Code :

```
 if(isset($params['session'])) {
        session_id($params['session']);
    }
 $uploadedFilesSession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('uploadedFiles'.$params['session']);
    if(!isset($uploadedFilesSession->files))
    {
        $uploadedFilesSession->files = array();
    }
    if(!isset($uploadedFilesSession->files[$flag])){
        $uploadedFilesSession->files[$flag] = array();
    }
```

Everytime it goes in condition **!isset($uploadedFilesSession->files)** and reset my authentication session too. It is only happening in Safari.

Please guide me.

Comment: Is this code running in an iframe by any chance?

Comment: I didn't check it in Iframe. Is there any possibility that this code may run in Iframe.